# How to unmask an IP with iptables?

Tags: iptables

Is there a way to unmask an IP using iptables?
I know to mask all-in-one is following by:

```
iptables -t nat -A -POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
```

Comment: May i know the purpose?

Comment: Sure. Let me show my scenario: pc->proxy->firewall->router>>>
my proxy mask pc ips to 192.168.2.#, but I want to send the real ip (e.g pc ip: 145.130.33.1) to another firewall placed in other place. I don't know if use DNAT o SNAT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot unmask an IP address that has been masqueraded. However, what you can do is to avoid masquerading the IP address in the first place. If your remote filewall was on address 172.16.1.254 then something like this should work:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING '!' --dst 172.16.1.254 -j MASQUERADE
```

Note that as you cannot route 192.168.0.0/16 addresses across the Internet you would need to have a private route to your remote firewall.

Comment: What if I try this? 
    iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING '!' -s 145.130.33.1 --dst 172.16.1.254 -j MASQUERADE

Comment: @Ronald, that says, "Masquerade everything except traffic coming from 145.130.33.1 and going to 172.16.1.254". Without seeing a network map showing all relevant hosts with their IP addresses by interface I'm not entirely sure how that differs in practical terms from my offering. Have you tried it? What happened?